# How can I create a tab view programmatically on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabview

For an iPhone app how can I create a tab view programmatically, preferably in Objective-C?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's quite simple to create a UITabBar via the [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). The following example should work within your AppDelegate class.

**App Delegate Interface**

Firstly, within the interface, we'll define our [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

**App Delegate Implementation**

Then, within the implementation file's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, we'll then initialise our tab bar controller.

```
// Initialise our tab bar controller
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
```

Next, you need to create the view controllers that you want to add to the tab bar controller. We'll need to add some information into these to set the tab's title/icon, but I'll come back to that at the end.

```
// Create your various view controllers
UIViewController *testVC = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *otherVC = [[OtherViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *configVC = [[ConfigViewController alloc] init];
```

As the setViewControllers:animated: method requires an array of view controllers, we'll add our view controllers to an array and then release them. (As the NSarray will retain them.)

```
// Put them in an array
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:testVC, otherVC, configVC, nil];
[testVC release];
[otherVC release];
[configVC release];
```

Then simply provide the UITabBarController with the array of view controllers and add it to our window.

```
// Attach them to the tab bar controller
[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];

// Put the tabBarController's view on the window.
[window addSubview:[tabBarController view]];
```

Finally, make sure you call `[tabBarController release];` within your `dealloc` method.

**View Controller Implementation**

Inside each of your view controllers, you'll also want to set the title and icon for the tab within the init method as follows:

```
// Create our tab bar item
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [self tabBarItem];
UIImage *tabBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE_NAME.png"];
[tabBarItem setImage:tabBarImage];
[tabBarItem setTitle:@"YOUR TITLE"];
```

Comment: When I create my own tabBarControllers programmatically, I always create a navigationController for each tab and each navigationController is initialized with a rootViewController. Seems to me that in your example it's not possible to create a navigation stack since you don't have a navigationController, but I never tried coding it like that.

Comment: @Wolfgang I suppose it depends on whether or not you'll want to push/pop items to the navigational stack. (My example is a pretty low end "just the basics" approach.)

Comment: @Kiran No problems - hope it goes well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is how we have to create tabbar programmatically

```
UINavigationController *BandNavigationController3;
AudienceSettingsViewController *audienceSettingsViewView =[[AudienceSettingsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AudienceSettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
BandNavigationController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:audienceSettingsViewView];
BandNavigationController3.tabBarItem.title = @"Settings";
BandNavigationController3.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"];

[BandNavigationController3.tabBarItem initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemFavorites tag:4];
BandNavigationController3.navigationBar.hidden = YES;

[bandTabBarArray addObject:BandNavigationController3];
[BandNavigationController3 release];
[audienceSettingsViewView release];

[tabBarController setViewControllers:bandTabBarArray]; 
[bandTabBarArray release];
```