# Make a tab switched layout with Objective-C iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

It is common design pattern that most mobile app use

```
+-------------------------+
|         title           |
+-------------------------+
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|        content          |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
+-------------------------+
| |tab1|   |tab2|  |tab3| |
+-------------------------+
```

The main idea is when user press tab1 or tab2 or tab3 the content will change accordingly.

What I am doing that now(with code not storyboard) is that make a `ViewController` to show the content and the bottom panel and make a `UINavigationController` to display the title

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];        
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];   
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

and when user press bottom tab change the content view while changing the content with `subviews`, but I found that when changing the content I found that:

- the view will not start properly margined with the height of title.
- furthermore, I should write all the logic in the same view controller which will cause the code a mess.

How to implement such a layout?

Comment: we often use a UITabbarController as the rootWindow, and contain several navagations inside it.

Comment: ya there is a preset TabBar application when you create new project. just select that. also, pls learn storyboard it will make your life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We often use UITabbarController as rootVC of Window.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    ViewController1 *vc1 = [ViewController1 new];
    vc1.tabBarItem.title = @"VC1";
    vc1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];

    ViewController2 *vc2 = [ViewController2 new];
    vc2.tabBarItem.title = @"VC2";
    vc2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];

    ViewController3 *vc3 = [ViewController3 new];
    vc3.tabBarItem.title = @"VC3";
    vc3.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];

    UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc1];
    UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc2];
    UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc3];

    UITabBarController *tab = [UITabBarController new];
    tab.viewControllers = @[nav1,nav2,nav3];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.window.rootViewController = tab;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

RelationShip between them:

[image]

When you click the tabbarItem, the view on windows changes between the viewController.View in the navation. They don't affect each other.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`UITabBarController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller), a default component that takes care of displaying the tabs icon in the bottom part of the screen and automatically manages the transition between the tabs. Each tab is also an independent view controller so your code is more organized. For the title then you can use a `UINavigationController` as the root controller for every tab you want to have the title bar

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920305/how-can-i-create-a-tab-view-programatically-using-objective-c) for a step by step guide.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Container View For Change the view on button Press without Tab bar controller ,See the url Below

[How to use a 'Container View' in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884879/how-to-use-a-container-view-in-ios)